# Softlayer Object Storage CDN HTTPS access

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We are currently working on a project implementing Object Storage CDN, the video content is going to be served up on a HTTPS site using JWPlayer. Is there a way for the CDN content to be accessed via HTTPS vs. HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look the following information:

[Enabling the SSL Option for CDN](https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/articles/enabling-ssl-option-cdn)

I hope this can help you.